# проблемы при подключении к интернету на ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, wifi

У меня есть модем, который раздает вай-фай, и есть ноутбук с убунтой 14.04.

Далее есть 3 ситуации:

1 - Я подключаюсь к интернету через вай-фай, у меня работает скайп, качаются торренты, могу гуглить, но кроме этого не могу перейти ни на один сайт, пишет ошибку `DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_BAD_CONFIG`.

2 - отключаю вай-фай, подключаюсь к роутеру через провод, в итоге интернета нет вообще, ошибка `ERR_NETWORK_CHANGED`.

3 - подключаюсь к роутеру через вай-фай и всовываю шнур, в итоге интернет работает.

Я хочу, чтобы работал первый и второй способы тоже, подскажите, с чем проблемы, я подозреваю, что что-то с настройками dns на компе...

Стоит дополнить, что с телефона подключаюсь по вай-фаю и интернет на нем работает.

Comment: А зачем Вам DNS на компе? Вы поставили DNS-сервер?

Comment: нет, ничего не ставил, но в ошибке написано про ошибку конфигурации dns, я правильно понял?

Comment: Ну, так гляньте в параметрах сетевого соединения, что там у Вас по поводу DNS написано. На память не помню, до дома доберусь - напишу подробнее

Comment: В Connection Information написано Primary DNS: 192.168.1.1 , больше нигде в подключении или настройках соединения dns не упоминается, если я правильно Вас понял)

Comment: 192.168.1.1 - это роутер?

Comment: ага, это он....

Comment: 1. приложите, пожалуйста, к вопросу вывод команды `ip a; ip r; cat /etc/resolv.conf` для всех трёх случаев (внести исправления в вопрос можно, нажав кнопку [edit] ниже текста вопроса). 2. уточните, как именно (в ноутбуке) вы осуществляете переподключения.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте сделать следующее:

Выполните команду

```
sudo resolvconf -u
```

Если появится ответ типа

```
/etc/resolvconf/update.d/libc: Warning: /etc/resolv.conf is not a symbolic link to /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf`
```

то выполните следующие команды:

```
sudo rm /etc/resolv.conf
sudo ln -s ../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
sudo resolvconf -u
```

Comment: у меня от команды  sudo resolvconf -u нет ошибок и ничего не изменилось или нужно перезагрузить комп? я просто сейчас не могу перезагружать.